# What is the best way to get in my template second/threeth object?

Tags: django

```
def myview(request):
    myobj = MyObject.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('x.html',{'myobj': myobj}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and

```
{% for o in myobj %}
    {{o.test}}
{% endfor %}
```

What is the best way to get in my template second/threeth object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`for` has `forloop` attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for):

```
{% for o in obj_queryset %}
    {% if forloop.counter == 2 %}Second{% else %}
    {% if forloop.counter ==3 %}Third{% endif %}
        {{ o.test }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you are just looking for the 2nd object from the queryset (and not print anything else), you can simply look up the second object ([see the docs for more about this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#variables)):

```
{{ obj_queryset.2 }}
```

Note that in your example, `myobj` isn't an object (ie. a model instance), it's a queryset.